# How to add type for react event function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I need help to add the type for `handleRowClick` which I am calling from one of the elements below. I did tried with `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLElement>` but it is giving me an error

> This expression is not callable.
> Type 'ChangeEvent' has no call signatures.

This error I am getting onClick function `onClick={() => handleRowClick(row.id)}`. The screenshot is attached. The `row.Id` is string type.

```
const DataTableBody: FC<{ rows: Array<DataTableRow>, handleRowClick: any }> = ({ rows, handleRowClick }) => {
    return (
        <TableBody>
            {rows.map(row => (
                <TableRow key={row.id} onClick={() => handleRowClick(row.id)}>
                    {row.cells.map(({ id, value }) => (
                        <DataTableBodyCell key={id} value={value} />
                    ))}
                </TableRow>
            ))}
        </TableBody>
    );
};
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkcAH.png)

Comment: What's `row.id`, is that a number or string?

Comment: It is a `string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click handler isn't an event, nor does it take the click event as a parameter, so you don't need to include it in the type. It looks like it only takes a string as a parameter, so all you need is

```
handleRowClick: (id: string) => void
```

and call it like:

```
onClick={() => { handleRowClick(row.id); }}
```